# Google SignIn Button crashes app when clicked on

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, crashlytics, gidsignin

I currently implement Google SignIn in my application. Today I received a notification from Crashlytics saying that the app had crashed during the sign in. A user also wrote in saying that they experienced the crash when they clicked on the actual "Sign in with Google" `GIDSignInButton`. They are from abroad so cannot debug from their device.

Now I have tried to replicate this many times and cannot seem to succeed. It works completely fine for me and others I asked.

The crash log from Crashlytics is:

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  ...                          0x10018b3f0 specialized AppDelegate.signIn(GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser : GIDGoogleUser!, withError : NSError!) -> () (AppDelegate.swift:313)
1  ...                          0x10018364c @objc AppDelegate.signIn(GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser : GIDGoogleUser!, withError : NSError!) -> () (AppDelegate.swift)
2  ...                          0x1002e0e10 __37-[GIDSignIn addCallDelegateCallback:]_block_invoke (GIDSignIn.m:1265)
3  ...                          0x1002d8fb8 -[GIDCallbackQueue fire] (GIDCallbackQueue.m:81)
4  ...                          0x1002e09dc __38-[GIDSignIn addDecodeIdTokenCallback:]_block_invoke_2 (GIDSignIn.m:1236)
5  GTMSessionFetcher              0x1007cf864 __71-[GTMSessionFetcher invokeFetchCallbacksOnCallbackQueueWithData:error:]_block_invoke (GTMSessionFetcher.m:2336)
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x187ed21fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x187ed21bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x187ed6b2c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 428
9  CoreFoundation                 0x188ff6810 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
10 CoreFoundation                 0x188ff43fc __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
11 CoreFoundation                 0x188f222b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
12 GraphicsServices               0x18a9d6198 GSEventRunModal + 180
13 UIKit                          0x18ef697fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
14 UIKit                          0x18ef64534 UIApplicationMain + 208
15 ...                          0x100084eac main (....swift:65)
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x187f055b8 (Missing)
```

I know it references two lines in the code but the second one the line does not even exist. The line on AppDelegate 313 does have the `user.serverAuthCode`. I am wondering if it crashes because this might become nil but then it would say that wouldn't it?

I was wondering if someone could help me debug this and try to figure out the cause of the crash?